# Getting a laravel run time exception when doing a video upload from post

Tags: laravel, file-upload

The error is **SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\wamp\tmp\php2625.tmp**

Controller action:

public function store() {

```
$file = Input::file("video");

$title = Input::get("title");
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$file->move('../../public/videos/' . $name);

$size = $file->getSize();

$post = Post::create(["title" => $title, "user_id" => Auth::id()]);


Video::create(["name" => $name, "post_id" => $post->id ]);


return Redirect::route("my_videos");
```

}

**$size = $file->getSize()**, apparently I cannot retrieve the size of the file, according to laravel debugger this seems to be causing the error.

I am uploading a 200kb file and upload_max_filesize = 64M, post_max_size = 10M in php.ini

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does the file exist? Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to support uploads?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

Yes the file does exist and I've used entype, I'll attach my form code.

Comment: Cant seem to paste in blade syntax html without it getting very messy, but again, I did use enctype. The file gets read properly, I've checked that, for some reason I cannot retrieve the file size though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for 
                    `$size = $file->getSize();`

before move operation

```
          $size = $file->getSize();
          $file->move('../../public/videos/' . $name);
```